# Выход из цикла ввода при нажатии кнопки enter

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как сделать выход из цикла при нажатии кнопки enter?

Калькулятор, раньше работал до ввода  '=',   теперь хочу сделать завершение цикла ввода при нажатии `\n`

`x = getchar(); if ( x == '\n')` не работает(

Comment: Не вижу цикла. *(1 символ нужен...)*

Comment: что не работает?  Почему не   показываете часть кода?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
do
{
...
}
while(cin.get()!='\n');
```